# Why doesn't my apply function return the length of the string?

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I'm trying to add a Pandas DataFrame column containing the length of the string in another column.

```
csv = pd.read_csv('data/sentiments.csv', dtype=str)
csv['length'] = csv['text'].astype(str).apply(len)
csv.head()

    text                                                 polarity   length
0    -Mi hijo es tan rico que le regalo un BMW a su...   NEUTRAL     64
1    The new BMW 3 Series is awarded 5 stars in the...   POSITIVE    64
2    @GEAGarratt BMW hand over 200 + electric vehic...   POSITIVE    64
3    I asked Sauber about more info or images of th...   NEUTRAL     64
4    bmw >>>                                             NEUTRAL     7
```

As you can see by the last column, it says each row is of length 64. While on the other hand, when I'm performing the following operation:

```
len(csv.iloc[0]['text'])
```

It correctly outputs the length to 140 for the first row.

What's wrong?

Comment: Just for the sake of trying something, does the same error happen if you replace your use of `apply` with `map` since you're looking to spray the operation onto a single `Series` object?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does.

Comment: Can you provide a small bit of code that would let us reconstruct the exact same data frame for the first 5 rows? And can you print out what the `dtype` of the `Series` is?

Comment: What if you try `csv['text'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))`?

Comment: How about `csv['text'].str.len()` ?

Comment: @xndrme: That worked! You wouldn't happen to know why, do you? I added some example data here: http://pastebin.com/UuQj0X5X

Comment: @waitingkuo: That worked as well!

Comment: @JimmyC I think the answer is in the answer of EMS, I really don't know why :(

Comment: Do you have any non-ASCII characters in `text`? I wonder if `astype(str)` is converting some of those improperly.

Comment: @TomAugspurger: Yes, plenty.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid possible issues with the type promotion logic of `astype` you can also try:

```
csv['length'] = csv['text'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)))
```

and you can also use `map` instead of `apply` since you're operating along the values of a `Series`.

Using this `lambda` is suboptimal compared with the natively vectorized `astype` so you should switch back from this workaround after figuring out the issue.

Some other possible confounders: (1) the `type` of the `Series` vs. the `type` of each element, (2) whitespace that is being truncated...

Answer (score 1):

Your codes and test data work fine in my computer. Make sure your pandas is not out of date. The latest stable version is 0.12 .

Pandas provides some [vectorized string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods). You can use

```
csv['length'] = csv['text'].str.len()
```

instead.

### Update

Thanks to @Jeff, the latest version 0.13 but not 0.12

Comment: Seems that I'm also out of date. Thank you :)